# Is there a better way to replace the actual shell in a script on a macOS/BSD-like OS?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, macos, bsd

I am using macOS. I have a shell script that doesn't work with `bash` but requires `zsh`. If I accidentally call it with `sh` (which is a very old bash on macOS) or `bash` I want it to replace `sh` or `bash` with `zsh` on the fly. Simply putting `#!/bin/zsh` at the start doesn't work, the executable bit is not set. I've come up with this in my script:

```
shell=`ps -p $$ -oargs=|cut -d " " -f1`
if test `basename $shell` != 'zsh'
then
    echo "Replacing shell with zsh"
    exec /bin/zsh $0 $@
fi

echo "ECHO $1 $2"
```

this works:

```
% bash test.sh aap noot
Replacing shell with zsh
ECHO aap noot
% zsh test.sh aap noot
ECHO aap noot
```

I was wondering if there is a better / more robust / more elegant solution to force a script to run only with zsh regardless with what shell it has been called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build up on [ZSH_VERSION](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-ZSH_005fVERSION)

```
#! /bin/zsh -
if [ -z "${ZSH_VERSION:-}" ]; then
  exec zsh - "$0" "$@"
fi
```